# What is a balanced tree?

Tags: graph-theory

I was going through [a handout](http://web.mit.edu/yufeiz/www/imo2008/tang-graph.pdf). It had the text (p.4):

> Let $G$ be a tree and $v$ be any vertex of $G$. Let $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots, v_t$ be vertices adjacent to $v$. Let $e_i$ be the edge joining $v$ and $v_i$. Let $T_i$ be subtree containing $v_i$ after removing edge $e_i$. Let $f(v)= \max_{i=1}^t |V(T_i)|$.
>
> Since $\sum |V(T_i)|=n-1$, if $f(v)$ is large, then the tree looks unbalanced. If $f(v) \approx (n-1)/t$ then the tree looks balanced.

however it didn't explain what a balanced graph is. What is a balanced tree?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "balanced tree" with your favorite search engine?

Comment: @JohnDouma It wouldn't really help, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple notions of a "balanced graph" in general, but [the handout](http://web.mit.edu/yufeiz/www/imo2008/tang-graph.pdf) isn't referring to any of them. It's somewhat related to the notion of balance used in [balancing binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), but that's actually optimizing a different quantity in a different context for a different purpose.

Instead, the word "balancing" is being used for intuition, and the intuition you should have is this. If $v$ is a vertex in an $n$-vertex tree $T$ with $\deg(v)=t$, then deleting $v$ from $T$ leaves a forest $T-v$ with $t$ components. (Each of $v$'s former neighbors is now in a different component of $T-v$.)

If there are $n$ vertices in $T$, there are $n-1$ in $T-v$, so the average order of a component is $\frac{n-1}{t}$. We defined $f(v)$ to be the maximum order of any component. Thus:

- If $f(v) \approx \frac{n-1}{t}$, then the largest component of $T-v$ is approximately average, which means *all* components must be approximately average. They are "balanced" in that each one has about the same number of vertices.
- If $f(v)$ is much larger than $\frac{n-1}{t}$, then the largest component of $T-v$ is much larger than average. The components are unbalanced: one has many more vertices than the others.

Often we split a tree by deleting an edge, and we would like the two resulting components to be as equal as possible. If we delete an edge $vv_i$, then one component of $T-vv_i$ is the component of $T-v$ containing $v_i$, and the other component is everything else. The best thing we can do is delete the edge to the largest component of $T-v$: in that case, one component has $f(v)$ vertices, and the other has $n - f(v)$.

Relatedly, for the "tree balancing exercise" on the next page of the hand out, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3966483) for why the upper bound on $\min_v f(v)$ isn't very good, and could be significantly improved. (To be fair, all we need is a lower bound on the smaller of $f(v)$ and $n-f(v)$, and $f(v)$ is usually the bottleneck there.)